# Lot of "file not found" when using sudo find / -type s

Tags: find, proc

In the attempt to understand why I keep getting the following error

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
```

while using the command `sudo find / -type s` the terminal prompted something like this

```
find: ‘/proc/31348/task/31348/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/31348/task/31348/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/31348/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/31348/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
```

What does this mean?

Comment: [What is the proc directory for? Why does it exist?](http://serverfault.com/questions/301980/in-unix-linux-what-is-the-proc-directory-for-why-does-it-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/proc` is a pseudo-filesystem, files under `/proc` don't actually exist on your hard drive. They contain information on currently running processes. These errors occur because some processes exited while `find` was running. It's totally normal.

(Actually, if you run `find` over and over again, and use a command such as `ps a | grep find` to get the PID of your `find` command, you'll see the same PID as the ones in the error messages. It's kind of like when you do `ps a | grep ps` the `grep` command will be "grapped" too.)

Comment: Should be said more accurately that `/proc` is virtual filesystem, in the sense that ot does have organization, and it does exist for the duration of the machine running.

Answer (score 3):

These errors happen because these files belong to a special filesystem [`procfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) (mounted at `/proc`). The *proc filesystem* presents information about processes in a hierarchical file-like structure, so at the moment when find tries to access these special files, they were no longer present.

To ignore these errors, add `-xdev` for GNU `find` (or `-x` for BSD `find`), e.g.

```
sudo find / -type s -xdev
```

> `-xdev` Don't descend directories on other filesystems.

See also: [How to exclude the folders proc and sys from search with find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193275/21471)

Answer (score 0):

find complains because she sees a zombie process with the process id 31348.

My find was complaining for process 4052 whenever I used her,

```
find: ‘/proc/4052/task/4052/ns/net’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/4052/task/4052/ns/uts’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/4052/task/4052/ns/ipc’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/4052/ns/net’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/4052/ns/uts’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/4052/ns/ipc’: No such file or directory

[root@mylaptop /]# ps -ef | grep 4052
root      4052  4043  0 Jun19 ?        00:00:00 [sh] <defunct>
```

So,

In my case it was a zombie process that was created a few hours ago (during a Linux operation of mine). The "kill -9 4052" had no effect of course, it was a zombie, and zombies can't be killed. Since it was only one and poor lonely zombie out there I just let it alone, till the next reboot.

: )